# What is the difference between phpinfo(); and php -i?

Tags: php

Search on DDG and in here didn't get any interesting results. I've heard they're different, but I want to know what makes them different and what advantage is there in having two different configurations ?

**EDIT** : Yes, I am running them both from the CLI.

Comment: One is a php command - the other is an argument to a binary file. You would never run `php -i` if you're getting the info through a browser. In your terminal both will return the same but `phpinfo` will format as HTML if run in a browser. [RTM: phpinfo() outputs plain text instead of HTML when using the CLI mode.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Comment: Are you running them both from the CLI?

Comment: @toomanyredirects yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`phpinfo()` is a language function that will display its output regardless of whether the script that it's executed in is called through the web SAPI or from CLI;

`php -i` is purely a command line switch to get information about PHP from the command line.

Why different configurations for web sapi and for CLI? Because you might have different requirements; often devs will run long command line scripts and  don't want the web sapi timeout applied, similarly with memory settings; and max file/post size ini settings are meaningless for CLI, so why bother having them in the cli ini file when they're only needed for the web?

Comment: and apparently `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` and `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` are both `-` if run through `phpinfo` compared to an empty string if they're run through `php -i`.

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on your server distribution, there may be separate php.ini
>   files for the command line and web server.

Source:

**Pro PHP
Patterns, Frameworks, Testing and More**
By *Kevin McArthur*

https://books.google.pl/books?id=CpUhDavmgSMC&pg=PT410&lpg=PT410&dq=%22php+-i+command%22&source=bl&ots=iljmNZ96ZU&sig=iRrX8_UjJWiOzlLtRz0zwJOtQJc&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicoq6NrsLLAhVjQZoKHeSSA8wQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22php%20-i%22&f=false

Comment: This tells us a reason we need phpinfo (or php-i) to help us understand the merged php.ini files, but does not answer the "what's the difference" question.

Answer (score -1):

`php -i` gives you the *same* info you got using `phpinfo()` **but**:

- can use a different set of INI files than your web server (so you can different *values* for some configuration parameters)
- it formats the data in a console-friendly way (no html tags, for example)

Edit:
don't digged the sources, but I can bet both uses the same code to extract their info .. in other words php -i is "calling `phpinfo()`" in a console-aware way and context

Comment: "*it formats the data in a console-friendly way*" - [so does `phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#refsect1-function.phpinfo-notes)

Comment: phpinfo() **can** .. it's different ;)

Comment: ... "can use a different set of ini files..."  That is a very vague statement, and not quite true as written.  What I think you mean to say, is that PHP can/will use different ini files for web server versus CLI.  But phpinfo() and php -i will always reflect the same set of ini files in the CLI environment (which is the only place php -i would usually be executed.))

Comment: You are right, I'm talking about the web server vs cli ... "can use a different set of INI files than your web server", in fact.

Comment: BTW, at the time of my answer the author didn't specified it was running both in CLI mode ;) Thanks for the downvote anyway