# Get PHP configuration from custom paths

Tags: php

I've using `PHP 7.3.5` as `FPM` with the option `user_ini.filename`.

The global `php.ini` will be resolved from `/etc/php/php.ini` and custom configurations will be resolved from `/var/users/<username>/<domain>/php.ini`.

How i can list the complete interpreted configuration without using `phpinfo()` method, specified on a based path like `/var/users/example/example.com/`?

By default, i can use `ini_get('display_errors')` - But its only contextual, depends on the script executement. On CLI i can use the argument/parameter `--with-config-file-scan-dir`, but i don't want to use an Shell environment like `shell_exec()`.

It is possible to use an PHP method to get an configuration value with their context/scope like `ini_get('display_errors', '/var/users/example/example.com/');`?

Answer (score 0):

`php -i` in command line will list you almost same information as `phpinfo()`. More on difference between `php -i` and `phpinfo()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36007063/7564018).

You can also see `php --ini` to see configuration files, however they might differ for fpm and cli.

**EDIT** Added loop that allows you to see where is ini value set.

```php
/**
 *  Get array of values that match given needle.
 *
 * @param string $needle
 * @param array $array 
 * @return array
 */
function search_in_array(string $needle, array $array): array 
{
    $values = [];

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $needle)) { // check wheter
            $values[] = trim($value); // paths to ini files contains spaces so we remove them.
        }
    }

    return $values;
}
/**
 *  Find given variable in set .ini file. 
 *
 * @param string $varname
 * @param string $ini 
 * @return string
 */
function get_ini_in_context(string $varname, string $ini): string
{
    $iniFile = parse_ini_file($ini);
    $phpIni  = parse_ini_file(php_ini_loaded_file());

    if (isset($iniFile[$varname]) && isset($phpIni[$varname])) {
        if ($iniFile[$varname] !== $phpIni[$varname]) {
            return $varname . ' is changed to ' . $iniFile[$varname] . ' in file ' . $ini . ' in php.ini it is ' . $phpIni[$varname];
        } else {
            return $varname . ' is same as in php.ini';
        }
    } elseif (isset($phpIni[$varname]) && !isset($iniFile[$varname])) {
        return $varname . 'is set only in php.ini';
    } else {
        return $varname . 'is not set in any ini file.';
    }
}

$inis = explode(',', php_ini_scanned_files());
$inis = search_in_array('xsl', $inis);

var_dump(get_ini_in_context('post_max_size', $inis[0]));
```

Comment: The problem is the output format. For sample `phpinfo()` returns an `HTML Document` - Here you must fetch the content with parsing. The same with the `CLI` usage - you must parse the output.

I wan't an solution **without parsing a generated output**, i wan't to get configuration values directly!

Comment: I think the down vote was not necessary. However, you can use `php_ini_scanned_files()` then look for the .ini file you want to read and read it via `parse_ini_file()`.

Comment: The Downvote was in favor because you didn't read my post. I'd like to quote once more:


`[...] but i don't want to use an Shell environment like shell_exec().`

Comment: Anyway, does the second proposed solution work for you? I think you'll need to write few loops, but it seems that PHP does not provide any other way how to get ini values and the file that contains them.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I have updated the answer with functions that allow you find where value is set. You can change returns to match your requirements.